# How to authenticate both frontend and backend using OIDC (vuejs + nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, authentication, vuex, openid-connect

I am building a single page application with a Vuejs frontend and a Nodejs backend. Been reading tons about single sign on and oidc, and managed to implement authentication using Oidc for the frontend, where I get a token from my identity provider.

Not sure however, now, how to also implement this for the backend and where/when/how.

So currently, when a user accesses the page, in my router.js file, this happens:

`router.beforeEach(vuexOidcCreateRouterMiddleware(store));`

In the store then, I do this:

```
Vue.use(vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // holds current list of products
    products: [],
  },
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  modules: {
    // initialize PING-OIDC module
    oidcStore: vuexOidcCreateStoreModule(
      oidcSettings,
      { namespaced: false },
      {
        userLoaded: (oidcUser) => {
          axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `${oidcUser.token_type} ${oidcUser.access_token}`;
        },
      },
    ),
  },
});

export default store;
```

So I set the authorization header, but now I am not sure where and how to proceed in the backend to also add + validate authentication there.

Very new to all this and there seem to be so many different way to proceed, so appreciate all the hints.

Currently, in server.js, I just do the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()) 

const cors = require('cors')
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:5002',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

//get mysql db here
const data = require('./app/config/db.config.js');
const db = data.MySQL_DB;

 //  show all products
app.get('/api/productlist',(req, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT ID FROM Product_Table";
  const query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("productIds ", results);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});


// Create a Server
var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

So should I create a `post` request in there as well? Just not sure on how to validate the request there.. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify which data/routes/pages you want to protect.

You log in from your client -> send to the server (ex : api/login) -> respond to your client with credential -> store the user and credential

see passport.js for express
see accesscontrol for your data server side

Note that routes in client can be easily hack